# Use variable content as index of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two string variables, and i would use it as index of array. I'm explain myself with example. If i have

```
$value1 = "mYvalue";
$value2 = "mySecondValue";
```

i would simulate the behavior of

```
$arrayFirsValue = $myArray['myValue'];
```

by using $value1 and $value2 values, like:

```
$arrayFirstValue = $myArray[$value1];
```

but it seems doesn't work. How can i do?
I need to use this method because i don't know in advice value1 and value2 values, so i can't use static strings

Comment: Define _it seems doesn't work_

Comment: Check the case:  `"mYvalue" !== "myValue"`

Answer (score 0):

Array keys are case-sensitive. `mYvalue` and `myValue` are NOT the same.

Once you have correct cases, `$myArray[$value1]` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`$value1` is `mYvalue` instead of `myValue`, so it does not work because array keys are case sensitive

Demo: https://eval.in/105206